# Trying to take the average of strings in a list and compare there counts in list to input file

Tags: python, string, list, mean

My list is currently

```
['AA11','AA11','AA22','AA33','AA44','AA44']
```

These are values of mine that through functions I returned and they work, I have a (count) for len of my original data file(AA** 10 of them) I want to (strip? split? enumerate?) this list and divide the count of each different string by the count of the original file, (in my list there are 2 counts for some strings) thus I would find an average for string,AA** would be in that list (count) times then take the average(mean? sum/count)? of that and return a (float?). AA11 is there twice, so 2/10 = .2 however AA22 is there once so 1/10= etc. and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple using the `collections` module and `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
common = Counter(yourList).items()
average = [(a, float(b) / len(common)) for (a,b) in common]
```

The result from running it on your given list:

```
>>> average
[('AA11', 0.5), ('AA33', 0.25), ('AA22', 0.25), ('AA44', 0.5)]
```

Comment: +1, but I would maybe replace `most_common()` with `items()` or `iteritems()` so that it is clear that all `average` will have all of the items.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks.  They do the same thing, but clearer is always better.

Comment: final edit: i want to take the count of each AA** in my list, (AA11 = 2 in my list above,and so on for AA12 etc),  then divide all the counts i get, by how many (non-repeated) AA** there are in the list, in the list above there are 4 non repeated AA** values @mattbryant

Answer (score 0):

It takes the list, then strips off 'AA' and then extracts the number part and then finds the number of times each number appeared.

```
from collections import Counter

a=['AA11','AA11','AA22','AA33','AA44','AA44']
num=list()
for index,val in enumerate(a):
    num.append(int(val.split('AA',1)[1]))
print Counter(num).items()
```

Comment: No, AA11 is a string in my list, and there are 11 AA11 in my original data file, I want to find how many AA11's i have in my list, then divide that count number by the number of AA11's in my data file, which i defined earlier as "count" @mattbryant